# Create program/daemon that launches on OS startup

Tags: startup, services, daemon

How do I create a daemon for *nix machines that starts up when the OS boots up? On MacOS, I am guessing the best option would be a brew service. What are the best options for linux?

Comment: Which Linux distro?

Comment: all desktop/developer flavors -  I have to write some generic, library code, but it doesn't need to run on servers, just desktop machines that developers use.

Comment: I don't appreciate a downvote without a comment mentioning why :) such that I can potentially rephrase the question, etc.

Comment: That can happen when the impression is that the OP didn't do enough research/thinking, which frankly is what it looks like, no offense. To Nick's point, it's the "init system" that you code daemons for. It's impossible to write daemons for "all" anything because there's really no standard init system. So you first need to review each distro you need to support and check which init system it uses. Note: by daemon I really mean the init system specific component; which typically delegates to the real daemon.

Comment: I did a couple google searches, even after some of those, no matter what, I would still ask a question on here, to see if there were any super new solutions. This is technology after all.

Comment: It's good that you did some Google searches, but what I'm saying is, that fact is not apparent in your question. I'm not saying that's why you got a down-vote, but it's quite possible given that: knowledge is acquired through effort. And since you can't pay knowledge here, the best "thank you" is to demonstrate that you seek to earn expertise. And you do that by showing you've done your homework. It didn't happen to you, but questions like this typically get a response of "And what have you done so far?" The "Software Recommendations" site is for when seeking new solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the distro, but many distros nowadays are moving towards `systemd` as the init service. For that case, you'd create a systemd service: see the systemd.directives(7) manpage, the [systemd homepage](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) and google for "systemd service example". Here's [one example (see example 9.18 in this section) which starts emacs as a daemon](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Create) :

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```